# Using tee to pipe ls and grep output into tail command without a script

Tags: linux, grep, tee

I have an issue running through log files.

I'm looking to use `ls` to create a list of files in the log directory and `grep` to run through for the specific instances/times the file ran. I only want to have the last line of each file so I want the `tail -1` command to run off the list of files `grep` provided.

I've tried multiple combinations of code that I've run across but have not had any luck so far; at this point it has become more of a curiosity than useful due to the amount of time I've spent on this. Below are a couple examples of the instances I have attempted:

```
ls | grep 2011_.._.._.._35_.* | tee >(tail -1)
ls | tee >(grep 2011_.._.._.._35_.*) | tail -1
```

Additionally, I would like to do this with a single command line if possible rather than creating a script and running a loop.

Answer (score 1):

**REVISED!**

had overread that you only want the last line of *each* logfile ...

The command you need is `xargs` not `tee`:

```
 ls | grep '2011_.._.._.._35_.*' | xargs -n 1 -- tail -1
```

or

```
 ls -1 2011_??_??_??_35_* | xargs -n 1 -- tail -1
```

This calls the command `tail -1` for each file that passes the `grep` command (1st case) or that is found by the ls command (2nd case).
Note that this will not work if a file contains spaces or newline. If you need an answer for that case, add a comment.

**EDIT**
For your comment:

```
ls -1 2011_??_??_??_35_* | xargs -n 1 -I FILE -- sh -c 'echo ; echo "FILE"; tail -1 "FILE"'
```

A little bit more complicated, but also handles files with spaces in the name.

Each `"FILE"` in the command sequence `echo ; echo "FILE"; tail -1 "FILE"` will be replaced by a line that `ls` outputs. This command sequence  will be passed to a shell and then executed.

Comment: This works great to extrapolate the last line from each file, thank you for the quick response. Is there also any way to have it list the file it has taken the last line from prior to the last line listed or is the output limited to the the individual pulled line.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you for the quick response and all the help

Comment: +1. Upvoted, although parsing `ls` is [not a good idea in general](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). But since this answer "worked perfectly" for the Original Poster, it deserves some appreciation. Too bad the OP went inactive and never formally accepted your answer.